# How can I write an XPath selector that picks only non-empty children?

Tags: xpath

I want to write an XPath expression that selects all non-empty `table:table-cell` children of the current element. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post some sample XML and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> XPath expression that selects all
>   non-empty `table:table-cell` children

In Xpath 1.0

```
table:table-cell[node()]
```

**Note**: This element is not empty:

```
<table:table-cell>Something</table:table-cell>
```

But the expression `table:table-cell[count(*) > 0]` does not select it, because it means: *all `table:table-cell` chindren having at least one **element** child*

Comment: Oh right. In my situation, the distinction didn't actually matter, but thanks for the explaination. Would `table:table-cell[count(node()) > 0]` be equivalent?

Comment: @Eric: Yes. That expression is equivalent but much more verbose. It's important to note that non empty node set's boolean value is true.

Answer (score 1):

Got it:

`table:table-cell[count(*) > 0]`