# Nokogiri parse XML with xpath

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xml-parsing, nokogiri

Im trying to figure out how to parse returned XMl via an api call, Im using Nokogiri and am trying to use xpath. What i would like to do is display all "title" attributes that have been returned

So far i have in a method

```
def getcontact
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(url))
doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry')
end
```

controller

```
@mycontacts = getcontact
```

View

```
<% @mycontacts.each do |c| %>
 <%= c.xpath("//title") %>
<% end %>
```

The XML

```
<entry>
 <id>xxx</id>
 <updated>xxx</updated> 
 <category  scheme="xxx"  term="xxx"/>
 <title type="text">xxx</title>
 <link rel="xxx" type="xxx"    href="xxx"/> 
 <link rel="xxx0gmail.com/b6ea0e8ddbc4e5"/>     
 <link rel="xx" type="xxx" href="xxx"/> <link rel="xx" type="axx" href="xxx"/> 
 <gd:email rel="xxx" address="xxx" primary="xx"/> 
</entry>
```

i am getting nothing returned, could someone point out what i am doing wrong please, also i notice there is html tags in the returned XML, can i strip this out, for example type=text is within the title attribute

Update

So i have tried this

```
doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry/xmlns:title').text
```

but this returns all the titles as a string

Update 2

View

```
<% @mycontacts.each do |c| %>
 <%= c.xpath('xmlns:title').text %><br>
<% end %>
```

method

```
doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry')
```

so this lists all my titles but if there are any blank entries there is an empty record. Need to remove these from the loop now i guess

Is this correct, is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: I think you're there short of the right xpath expression.  This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573643/how-can-i-write-an-xpath-selector-that-picks-only-non-empty-children .

Comment: hmm, how would i implement this into my setup? any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With method 2, try using:

```
d.xpath('//feed/entry[title[node()]]'
```

This will return a nodeset containing nodes that have a non-empty title.  Then you can iterate over set however you like.

Comment: thanks, changed to doc.xpath('//xmlns:feed/xmlns:entry[xmlns:title[node()]]') and works great...would you happen to know how to select address from <gd:email rel="xxx" address="txxx" primary="xxx"/>

Comment: Try: c.xpath('email/@address').text().  E.g. pick out the address attribute of the email tag under the current node, and then return it's text value.